# Meteor up bcrypt error on invoking deployment process

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

I am deploying my meteor project Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with meteor up package.
I have got this error. I am behind the proxy , so I added proxy set up. wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz works fine. Do not understand what is the problem here.

[192.168.81.206] ✘ Invoking deployment process: FAILED

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.81.206' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.35 | linux | x64
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/mce/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
=> re-installing binary npm module 'bcrypt' of package 'npm-bcrypt'
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: log shows you're node@0.10.35? I thought Meteor is node@0.10.33?

Comment: node version 33 or above should be no problem. I used my other project node v.35 it worked fine.

Comment: This happens because you're behind a proxy, I'm not sure how to set it but you need to make sure the npm installer being used also uses this proxy.

Comment: Make sure you're AWS security group settings are correct, this was one of my issues.